# How do I achieve the translucent effect of navigation bars and tool bars for nested views in iOS 7?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uitoolbar

If I use a standard `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`, navigation bars and tool bars appear translucent on top of the content. However, if I use my own custom view hierarchy, I no longer see the effect. In the following screenshot, you can see that the table view does not appear underneath the sticky toolbar.

[image]

The `UIToolbar`'s is initialized like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.translucent = YES;
        self.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1f];

        // irrelevant code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

The actual `loadView` of the `UIViewController` is quite long, so I'll just show a diagram of the layout:

```
 ___________________________
|  _______________________  | <-- UIView (self.view)               
| |                       | |
| |  UITableView          | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |                       | |
| |_______________________| |
|  _______________________  |
| | UIToolbar             | |
| |_______________________| |
|___________________________|
```

I made sure to set the edges for the extended layout in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
```

The documentation for [edgesForExtendedLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout) is a one liner, so I'm stuck on what other interrelated things need to be put into place to get the tool bar to be translucent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tableView should extend and fill the entire view. Then you can set a contentInset which is the height of the navigation bar on the top as well as the toolbar on the bottom. That way you can see the content flow right through. Heres a snippet of code on how to do that. Make sure that the tableView is right at the bottom of the view hierarchy and that the navigation bar and toolbar are on top of it.

```
 self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(NavBarHeight, 0, ToolBarHeight+distance_Of_ToolBar_FromThe_Bottom_of_view, 0);
```

Comment: I tried that, but the UIToolBar is still quite opaque. Even if I set the `barTintColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`, you'd have to squint to see anything behind it.

Comment: Have you tried to set `toolBar.translucent` = YES; ?

Comment: Already have that. Anyway, I just decided to go with a normal UIView so that I can control the opacity.